# Writing data from Arduino with user_id into database

Tags: php, database, session, arduino, storing-data

I need help with my project. I have www page, where is possible create user registration and users can log into this page. I also have there page with Arduino project (Arduino have form with buttons and it's included into page with iframe function). This page with project is protected by conditions - user must by logged and only one user can use this page in one time. After user use login form, I have his name in Session like this code:

```
 $_SESSION['log_user'] = $user_name;
 $escape = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$user_name);
```

I am working with this session on main page index, where its used for auto-logout and for monitoring who is logged.

**So problem is:** If the user runs the Arduino project, press the button: send! All measured values ​are written to the database. I edited the script to write the date into database too. But I need to know, who save the data. The problem is that the script does not even want to write the name of the logged-in user stored in session. All data are stored, only name is empty. But when I log into www page and run this script from manually, echo show me correct user from session and its even saved with date too (without values from project of course).

So please how is even possible that is not working correctly when user press button from project? Name is again empty. I have no idea how write this information with Arduino values too. (By the way, for sending Arduino data you am using get method.) I must somehow check if exist session and use some condition to write it?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$spojeni = mysqli_connect("*****","*****","*****","****");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$_SESSION['log_user'] = $user_name;
$escape = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$user_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {echo "Connection failed !" . mysqli_connect_error();}
$pwm = ($_GET["pwm"]);
$av = ($_GET["av"]);
$bv = ($_GET["bv"]);
$write = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `optoclen` (`PWM`,`MB1`,`MB2`,`User`, `Date`) 
                                            VALUES ('$pwm','$av','$bv','$escape','$date')") or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 
?>
```

Comment: `$user_name` isn't set anywhere.

Comment: I just dont give here  complete code of my connecition script. When user write all infomations into login form correctly, i just select the user_name, save them into session log_user session.